# SQL Server - sequence behind the view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

I would like to isolate query next value of the sequence on the database side so my application just needs to query from view and it obtain its unique id of process.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_VID MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647;
CREATE VIEW VID AS SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_VID AS ID;
-- I got following error:
-- NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in check constraints, default objects, computed columns, views, user-defined functions, user-defined aggregates, user-defined table types, sub-queries, common table expressions, derived tables or return statements.
```

While the approach works fine on *postgres* and *h2* db it looks it will not work for sqlserver.
I've found nice post about the limitations of sequences in sql server [here](http://sqlhints.com/2013/08/18/sequence-limitations-and-restrictions-sql-server-2012/).

So the question is how can I achieve isolation of quering from sequence in case of MS sqlserver, so my application dont have to be db vendor aware?

Comment: Would stored procedure be ok?

Comment: @JamesZ no, I use plain SQL interface to obtain the unique ID for a process. If I can put SP exec behind the view and just query the view then sure it could be OK but I assume it is less probable than just a sequence behind the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NEXT VALUE FOR` function in SQL Server has several restrictions. One of these restrictions is that the `NEXT VALUE FOR` function cannot be used in a View.

From the documentation on [NEXT VALUE FOR (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx#Anchor_4) - Limitation and Restrictions:

> The NEXT VALUE FOR function cannot be used in the following situations:
>
> - In views, in user-defined functions, or in computed columns.

---

You will have to find another way of doing things. I would suggest creating a Stored Procedure that would return a next value as an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Views and functions can't cause side-effects. This is a good thing because it makes them reliable when used in a bigger query. There is no way to circumvent this limitation. The product team makes sure of that.

What you are doing there is an anti-pattern even when using a database where it is technically possible. Don't hide side-effects in views.

Use a procedure or direct T-SQL code.

Comment: Can you provide an sqlserver example to isolate ms sqlserver specific code on the database side, if not behind the view then using any other object - can be SP, so I can simply obtain id by submitting a db-vendor in-aware query from the application?

Comment: Do you have any specific problem with doing this? Can't you just write a one-liner procedure? That should work cross database.

Comment: Is it possible to return the result of that procedure behind the view? (maybe a table valued fun?) So I can just query view from the application? If so that would be good enough!

Comment: No because as I said views can't cause side effects. You are still trying to cheat SQL Server. It's not possible. The devs make sure that there is no way you can cause side effects from views or functions. I explained why. You need to throw this away and move past denial stage.

Comment: This sounds silly because `SELECT` statement can do side effect but `VIEW` cannot. This would not be a bug but a feature.

Comment: SELECT cannot do side-effects either. Ever. (Except when using SQL CLR...). This is the whole point! The query optimizer must be able to assume that nothing in a SELECT side effects. Execution order is not defined in any way. Side-effects would be unpredictable.

Comment: select statement `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_NAME` returns the sequence next value and as a side effect it increments the sequence.

Comment: OK, I take that back. Good to know! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx This is then the only special case I know of. The docs are very explicit about how the sequence numbers are drawn. They specify an execution model which nothing else I know of has.

Comment: NEXT VALUE FOR cannot be used "In subqueries including common table expressions and derived tables.". That's the reason it is not allowed in views. Views are inlined into the outer query plan. They behave like a derived table. But I agree with you that it would be possible to make the engine support that. It's just an unwise thing to do.

Comment: regarding approach you proposed, do you know any stored procedure call/exec which would be the same for h2, postgres, sqlserver, oracle? So I can go with the SP approach and still have application not aware of db vendor?